# QGIS MCDA - Ground source heat pump implementation

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS for a dissertation project. I am aiming to try and theorise an appropriate point to implement a ground source heat pump (GSHP's) within an area.

The data I have access to is the locations of approx 11k properties

I also have the current number of GSHP's within the area

I have formulated a spreadsheet which has got approximate values for the benefits of implementing a GSHP at each property

I have base map which includes a boundary of the area I am testing within

Sadly however I am unsure what process I should be using on QGIS (only system I can use) and additionally if any other data would be required to use a certain process.

If anyone can reply to this enlightening me on what further data I may require, or how I should be running this process please can you help.

Additionally if you need me to describe this further please reply to the post and I'll try and further explain.

Comment: "what further data I may require": to me, this sounds like a question you should ask your supervisor. It's not a question that deals with the technical/software aspect, but with research design.

Comment: My supervisor has gone on leave unfortunately, Just thought I'd post my project on here in the hope that someone may understand what I am trying to do, I am thinking that in terms of other data the topography may be required based on other similar literature, But I am unsure if this would be necessary? (taking into account the approximate values table)